# NextJS + Express + Now deployment. Won't Boot, Even Demo Wont Boot

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

Trying to run an SSR NextJS app, and I need a small handful of specific routes defined to do specific backend tasks. For example, when a form is submitted, I want to do server stuff to send an email with the form data to the website owner. But that's not the problem....

The problem is that I can't get a node server to boot using express on the Zeit/Now platform. Not even the NextJS + Express example will work!

Here's the example URL they provide on GitHub.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/custom-server-express

If I clone that directory and then deploy it with the `now` command, I get this:

[Unchanged Demo Not Working](https://custom-server-express-app-as1frrxkn.now.sh)

After reading some docs, I decided I should add a `now.json`, as shown below. Unfortunately, the demo is still not working! :( Here's what I added.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "nodejs-express",
    "builds": [
    { "src": "server.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }
  ]
}
```

Aside from the above `now.json` file, the project is an *exact duplicate* of the example project, which you can see above. I'm simply trying to get it to boot before I port over my existing static app.

There's a 3-day old GitHub issue on this exact issue, but I was hoping this is originating from my own misunderstanding and that a kind soul on SO could help. [Here's the GitHub Issue](https://github.com/zeit/now-examples/issues/196). I've spent at least 8 hours over several days trying different things and, imo, it's time to ask for help.

Thanks for reading! Drop questions below so I can respond.

---

**EDIT:** This appears to be a *Zeit/Now* platform issue as of Dec 24, 2018. Leaving the question up for others. Will update and/or delete this question when the issue has been resolved. [See the official GitHub issue report here](https://github.com/zeit/now-examples/issues/196).